# Extracting array and return it as array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I want to iterate through `array1` as I search my database according to the value of the current index of that array `array1`, and insert all the data found into `array2`.

The issue is that I am getting only one record into `array2` currently.

```
$id = $this->input->get('name'); //array
    foreach ($id as $ids) {
    $this->db->where('employee_id',$ids);
    $query = $this->db->get('employee');
    return $query->result_array();
```

Please help me.

Comment: is name an array in the html form? are there multiple fields with `name=name[]` ?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: The `return` will end your `foreach` loop after one iteration. You should try to append all the results to an array and then return that array _after_ the loop.